# Remove the image and rearrange the ID's number automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say that I have selected four images from my computer into the file-input-form, and all the four images are previewed before being uploaded. Each selected image will have an `unique id`: the first image will have the id of 1, the second image has the id of 2, and so on for the third and the last image.

The problem is, ***if I remove the second image***, then the arrangment of the `image's ID` will be:

---

`<img id="img_1">`
`<img id="img_3">`
`<img id="img_4">`

---

While the id for the image number two (`<img id="img_2">)` has been removed from the structure above.

What I want is, if the second image is remove, then the third image will change the  position of that image **where the id of the third image** should be: (`<img id="img_2">)` and the id of the fourth image** should be: (`<img id="img_3">)`

Here is the code for removing the image:

```
$('body').on('click','.boxclose','',function(e){
   var spanid = $(this).attr('id');
        var splitval = spanid.split('_');
        $('#div_' + splitval[1]).remove();
});
```

Here is the code for previewing the image:

```
         var ftype = new Array(), count1 = 0;

    $("#imgInput").change(function () {
        readURL(this);

    });
    function readURL(input) {
        var files = input.files;
        var output = document.getElementById("result");



        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            var divid = 'div_' + i;
            var spanid = 'span_' + i;
            var count = 0;
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                var picFile = event.target;
                var picnames = files[count].name;
                var mimetypes = picFile.result.split(',');
                var mimetype1 = mimetypes[0];
                var mimetype = mimetype1.split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
                count++;
                count1++;
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + count);
                div.setAttribute('class', 'divclass');
                if (mimetype.match('image')) {
                    div.innerHTML = "<img id='img_" +  count1 + "' class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                        "title='" + picnames + "' width='96' height='80' alt='Item Image' style='position:relative;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;' data-valu='" + mimetype + "'/><span class='boxclose' style='cursor:pointer' id='span_" + count1 + "'>x</span>";

                }

                output.insertBefore(div, null);

            });

            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
```

Let's see in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/u614zjmj/embedded/result/), and try to select four images from computer, and then remove the second image. And then inspect the elements. The arrangements of the IDs are not structured anymore after one of the image is removed.

Comment: could you interpret them on the server side and arrange them after upload ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Can you help me and show me how to do that, please?

Comment: well what are you trying to achieve and there might be a better way around it than manipulating the dom.. Is this for an image uploader ?

Comment: If what you mean is to re-arrange them manually, it is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes this is for an image uploader. I need to upload some images with unique ID. Do you have a differet method how to achieve this?

Comment: the code you have is perfectly valid to generate a unique id.. they might be out of order in the DOM but they are unique, when the images are posted to your server side you can arrange them how you like.. Unless im missing something ?

Comment: The main idea you give to me is `"arranging the posted files (images) on the server side"`. Can you give me the links of tutorials how to do this? Because I am not sure if you are missing something here if you have got that what I want is structuring ID's of image (1,2,3,4,...) after one of images is removed.

Answer (score -2):

Do You have to use id's ? Try adding class to each image, and ond the very end use

```
$('.<classname>').eq(<index of element/image>)
```

Comment: id's should be used as they are unique items.. Also im not sure how this answers the question ..

Comment: Yes, I need the id of each images because that will be fetched on its each placeholders. Adding class to each image? I think each image has have the same class which is `thumnail`?